# update elasticsearch data that is already uploaded with logstash and filebeat

Tags: elasticsearch, logstash, updates, filebeat

we have a question: we are using logstash with the forwarder filebeat. We have already uploaded 21 Million logs and now we have a change in our config file in logstash. We don't want to delete all the data and reload it so we want to know if there's a way to update a field. But we don't want to update each field, only if there is a specific content in it.
Can anyone help us and maybe give an code example?
Thanks for your help!

```
    {
  "_index": "logstash-2016.06.06",
  "_type": "log",
  "_id": "4f63b12b098bd5ff02de89e7057347c8ea39ae96",
  "_score": null,
  "_source": {
    "message": "[06/Jun/2016:23:59:58 -0700] \"GET CFNetwork/758.4.3 Darwin/15.5.0\"",
    "@version": "1",
    "@timestamp": "2016-06-06T21:59:58.000Z",
    "type": "log",
    "fields": null,
    "beat": {
      "hostname": "xxx",
      "name": "xxx"
    },
    "source": "xxx",
    "offset": xxx,
    "input_type": "log",
    "count": 1,
    "host": "xxx",
    "iOSVersion": "Unknown",
    "tags": [
      "beats_input_codec_plain_applied"
    ],
    "@uuid": "79e6a34e-13e4-9b5b-467b3a1f04fa",
    "fingerprint": "xxx",
    "logDate": "06/Jun/2016:23:59:58",
    "timezone": "0700",
    "httpRequest": "GET",
    "network": "CFNetwork",
    "CFNetworkNumber": "758.4.3",
    "DarwinVersion": "Darwin",
    "darwinVersionNumber": "15.5.0"
  },
  "fields": {
    "@timestamp": [
      1465250398000
    ]
  },
  "sort": [
    1465250398000
  ]
}
```

So we get the iOSVersion by using the CFNetworkNumber and the DarwinVersion in a matching table in the logstash config. In this exampe the iOSVersion is unknown because this combination is not in the config yet. So I want to add a this case and update those documents wehre it is unknown but the cas is known after this change. So what I add in the logstash config is this:

```
else if [darwinVersionNumber] == "15.5.0" { 
    if[CFNetworkNumber] == "758.4.3" {
        mutate{
            gsub => ["iOSVersion", "Unknown", "9.3.2"]
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: you should maybe provide a concrete example. Show a document that is already in ES and what changes are required?

Comment: I added an example.

Comment: Ok, the problem is that `darwinVersionNumber` and `CFNetworkNumber` are not in your documents, so I'm not sure how you can identify which documents you need to update. Do you have any other field of your ES document you can use?

Comment: Sorry it was a bad example because there was a grokparsefailure. I have changed it! Normally we have both fields!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are on ES 2.x, you can simply use the [update by query](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/docs-update-by-query.html) endpoint in order to update those documents with the following query

```
POST /logstash-*/_update_by_query
{
  "script": {
    "inline": "ctx._source.iOSVersion = '9.3.2'"
  },
  "query": {
    "bool": {
      "filter": [
        {"term": {"iOSVersion.raw": "Unknown"}},
        {"term": {"darwinVersionNumber.raw": "15.5.0"}},
        {"term": {"CFNetworkNumber.raw": "758.4.3"}}
      ]
    }
  }
}
```

If you're still on ES 1.x, then you can use the [update by query plugin](https://github.com/yakaz/elasticsearch-action-updatebyquery) which does the same thing

Comment: thanks so much! It workes (after enabeling scripting)!